# Adobe AIR NativeProcess class doesn't exist

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript, air

I have an application that was written for AIR 1.5.3 with Flex SDK 3.5. I need it to use NativeProcess to coummunicate with an exe. So I changed the Flex SDK to 3.6 and the AIR version in the xml descriptor file to 2.5, it reads:

```
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/2.5">
```

I also added the versionLabel and versionNumber entities to the xml. The application compiles and runs fine. However the NativeProcess class still can't be imported from flash.desktop. What am I missing here?

EDIT: I also have extendedDesktop in the supportedProfiles in the app descriptor.

Comment: I'm pretty sure AIR 2 (and thus NativeProcess) didn't exist at the time of Flex 3.5. You'll have to compile with a more recent SDK or manually add a newer playerglobal.swc library.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add:

```
<supportedProfiles>extendedDesktop</supportedProfiles>
```

in the Application Descriptor?

Comment: Yes I added that as well.